# How does grail's <g:layoutBody/> tag work?

Tags: grails

I've been just brought on to a grails project and I'm unfamiliar with the language.  In one of my gsp files there is a `<g:layoutBody/>` tag that seems to be generating a lot of content somehow.  How does this tag work?

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/theWebLayer.html#layouts

Comment: [Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/layoutBody.html) can help with the definition of what each tag do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`g:layoutBody`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/layoutBody.html) tag is usually used in layout files, it renders the content of the body of the page which is using that layout.

Together with [`g:applyLayout`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/applyLayout.html), [`g:layoutHead`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/layoutHead.html) and [`g:pageProperty`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/pageProperty.html) it makes the basics of GSP templating functionality, it's worthy to check out more closely how to use them.